# How to fix "Physical file does not exist" error in SAS EG

Tags: sas

I am using SAS Enterprise guide. SAS EG is running on a UNIX server, and I am using a Windows machine. I want to input files in SAS EG for an analysis using INFILE.

The file EXAMPLE.txt is saved on a windows shared drive, which is connected to a folder on the server running SAS EG. The path of EXAMPLE.TXT on the Windows Shared folder:

> I:\projects\RWDS\rwds_1619\SASDATA

I can open EXAMPLE.TXT in SAS EG when I go

open - open data - Example.txt

The content of the file is displayed properly in the SAS Process Flow. The path on files on the server, which I can see on SAS EG, is:

> W:\projects\RWDS\rwds_1619\SASDATA\EXAMPLE.TXT

When I try to input the files in SAS EG using INFILE command, I get this error:

> ERROR: Physical file does not exist.
>   /var/opt/teradata/sas/config/Lev1/SasApp/W:\projects\RWDS\rwds_1619\SASDATA\EXAMPLE.TXT

I used this code:

```
DATA MYDATA;

data new;

INFILE 'W:\projects\RWDS\rwds_1619\SASDATA\EXAMPLE.TXT';

INPUT ID $ 1-3 GP $ 5 AGE 6-9 TIME1 10-14 TIME2 15-19 TIME3 20-24;

PROC MEANS DATA=MYDATA;

RUN;

TITLE;FOOTNOTE
```

Expected result is to load the file EXAMPLE.TXT into SAS EG

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: If it is a shared folder then ask your IT team to share it with the Unix server that SAS is running on. Then use the unix path where they mounted it instead of the drive letter you are using on your PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This confirms you are running SAS on Unix/Linux

```
ERROR: Physical file does not exist. /var/opt/teradata/sas/config/Lev1/SasApp/W:\projects\RWDS\rwds_1619\SASDATA\EXAMPLE.TXT
```

You will need to specify the filename using the server point of view.

```
/unix-specific-file-path-to/EXAMPLE.TXT
```

Comment: Problem is that in SAS EG, I am only able to see the path W:\projects\RWDS\rwds_1619\SASDATA\EXAMPLE.TXT

I cannot see the parent directories.
Is it possible to load or copy the file in a different way?

Comment: @Zipfer you can use the import wizard to click and import your file. Import wizard can reference local files, which it transfers to the grid network or Unix server side.